# Enforcing time-limit on the client

Tags: language-agnostic

Suppose you have a web application and you want to user to execute a particular action (e.g., answering a quiz question) within a specific time limit. What is the best way to enforce the time limit? I can think of two, with pros and cons:

- client-side enforcement: works but susceptible to tampering
- server-side enforcement: cannot be tampered with but may cause problems due to latency between server and client

any thoughts?

Comment: Depends on what kind of time limits you want to enforce, I guess. If they can be measured in minutes, latency won't play too big a role, I think.

Comment: I agree, but if we are talking about seconds (5 to 10), latency might be an important factor.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest client side enforcement, backed by server side sanity check. You could allow for latencies up to 30 seconds, or some other reasonable value on the server side, and declare client side tampering if the difference is too large.

Of course, this will allow for client side tampering, but only up to a certain amount of time that you allow for.

---

After writing the comment below, I thought of the following: you cannot trust the client's javascript to ping your server on page load for latency calculation - it is trivial to hijack it. But I don't know how I would cheat a redirect response. Prior to starting the test, you could take a time stamp and return a redirect response. Then you can calculate the latency on the server side on the redirected page. You could even do it a few times to get an average. I don't know how hard it would be to delay serving the redirect page request, but it may provide an extra layer of protection. Also it may allow you to give more realistic latency bounds.

Comment: Yeah, this seems like a viable solution. However, if the time limit is on the order of seconds (5 to 10), then a large latency tolerance might be attractive enough to exploit and a smaller latency tolerance  might not be enough...

Comment: @Mohammad I am afraid this is the best I can think of. You could attempt to model the latency using something like the NTP algorithm (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol#Clock_synchronization_algorithm), but it doesn't work when one peer is untrusted (i.e. the client).